# Find out if texture contains at least one black pixel in WebGL?

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, shader

Is there a special webGL trick to check if a texture contains at least one black rgb pixel, without having to read pixels on CPU ?

To me, it seems that checking pixels on CPU is the only solution. In this case,
is there a way for example, to compress a high resolution texture to a 1x1 texture containing a single boolean color information, so that I only have to read one single pixel for performance reason.

Thanks !

Comment: trick: no; way to down sample texture to 1x1: yes many; that being more performant than checking on the CPU: probably not

Comment: what I mean by downsampling texture to 1x1 is reducing a texture to a 1x1 pixel color having information about texture containing a black pixel or not... but it doesn't seem doable due to GPU parallel computing.

Answer (score 0):

Only idea I have is erm... at least complex.

Lets say we have texture with dimension N, then:

- Make canvas 1x1 pixel large.
- Create array of N*N points, each point with different [x,y] attributes representing pixel position we will look for.
- In vertex shader do texture lookup based on the point position. If the color of that pixel is not black then `discard`;
- Set point position [0,0]
- In fragment shader simply draw black color (assuming we have white canvas) for point.

Then what you have is 1x1 canvas with black color if there were any black pixels, or white color if there werent any and you can simply read it with cpu.

The bottle neck in this case is second step = point array building, and also cpu-gpu communication. This will run faster only if you need to do a lot of reads in short time and if you know size of the texture before the application runs so you can reuse same buffer for points for all textures.

Comment: interesting. i'll try to investigate. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just idea, not sure if it would work.

Make a render target, draw your texture into it using a shader that draws white if the pixel is rgb 0,0,0 and black otherwise. Let's assume is 1024x768 and now has 1 white pixel. Draw that into a texture 1/4 it's size. In this case 512x384. With linear filtering on if we have the worst case, just 1 white pixel then it will average to 0.25 (63). We can do that 2 more times first to 256x192, then again 128x96. That one original white (255) pixel will now be (3). So run the black/white shader again and repeat 64x48, 32x24, 16x12, run the black/white shader, then again 8x6, 4x4, 2x2, run the black/white shader. Then 1x1. Now check If that's not pure black there was at least 1 black pixel.

Instead of doing a 1/2 size reduction each time you could try reducing those 3 levels into one by averaging a bunch of pixels in a shader. 15x15 pixels for example would still leave something > 0 if only 1 pixel was white and the rest black. In that case starting at 1024x768 it would be

```
1024x768 -> 67x52 -> 5x4 -> 1x1
```

I have no idea if that would be faster or slower.